# Trying to count number of rows returned from MySQL joined table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm trying to count the number of rows returned from a MySQL joined table, i.e.:

```
select *, count(pets.id) as pets_per_owner 
from owners 
left join pets 
   on owners.id=pets.owner_id
```

The problem is all the joined rows are grouped.

Is there any way to get these subtotals, but displaying all rows returned (ungrouped) without separate queries?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an aggregate function with no `GROUP BY` so the results are being reduced into a single row.

MySQL uses an extension to GROUP BY which allows columns in the select list to appear outside of an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause, this however can lead to unexpected results. (see [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html))

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

In order to fix this you should do two things, first replace the `select *` with the actual names of the columns that you need to return.  Second use a GROUP BY on the columns that you are including in the select list that are not being aggregated. For example:

```
select owners.name, count(pets.id) as pets_per_owner 
from owners 
left join pets 
   on owners.id=pets.owner_id
group by owners.name
```

Since you posted code in the comments it is difficult to determine exactly what you are looking for but if you want the pet names along with the total count, you could use one of the following:

```
select o.name,
  p.name pet_name,
  p2.pets_per_owner
from owners o
left join pets p
  on o.id = p.owner_id
left join 
(
  select owner_id, count(*) pets_per_owner
  from pets
  group by owner_id
) p2
  on o.id = p2.owner_id
  and p.owner_id = p2.owner_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a56/4)

Or you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function to list the pet names in a single row:

```
select owners.name, 
  group_concat(pets.name separator ', ') pet_name,
  count(pets.id) as pets_per_owner 
from owners 
left join pets 
   on owners.id=pets.owner_id
group by owners.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a56/6)

Comment: I tried, but Stackoverflow won't allow me to edit 2 characters long.

Comment: @bluefeet Here are my two tables:  +----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Mary  |
|  2 | Steve |
+----+-------+  +----+-------+----------+
| id | name  | owner_id |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Corky |        1 |
|  2 | Spud  |        2 |
|  3 | Max   |        2 |
+----+-------+----------+  Running your query:  +-------+----------------+
| name  | pets_per_owner |
+-------+----------------+
| Mary  |              1 |
| Steve |              2 |
+-------+----------------+  Steve's pets are grouped. I need Steve's pets each given a row of their own, with the displayed in each.

Comment: @bluefeet apologies for formatting, this is my first post here and as you can see I'm clueless how this process works. Your first example is exactly what I was looking for. For future reference, should I edit your answer directly if I want to include new code?

Comment: @user1604580 Glad you got it working. If you want to include code, then you should edit your original question and post the code there.  It is very difficult to see code in the comments. :)